# Bloomberg APIv3 Get reference data overrides

Tags: bloomberg

I have an Excel function that I want to move into Python. The BDP function is:

`=BDP("IBM US Equity","BEST_EBITDA","BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE","1FY")`

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal 
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA")
```

how do I add overrides to this request?

I've tried:

`resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA",["BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE","1FY"])`

`resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA","BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE","1FY")`

`resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA",["BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE=1FY"])`

Comment: This is really a question for the Help Desk. F1F1

Answer (score 0):

`overrides=[BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE=1FY]`, then pass the overrides in the get_reference_data as the last parameter.

Comment: i've tried `overrides=['BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE=1FY']`. Then `resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA",overrides)` ... but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data('spx index', 'indx_members')
members = resp.as_map()['spx index']['indx_members']
members = members.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' US EQUITY')
mnemonics = [
    '5YR_AVG_RETURN_ON_INVESTED_CPTL', 
    'BEST_EPS_NXT_YR'
]
overrides = [
    'BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE = 1FY'
]
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data(members, mnemonics, overrides)
resp.as_frame().head()
```